# Server Load for Laravel Command Bus

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm building a Laravel 5 eCommerce site with a custom shopping cart and admin, and I'm thinking that using commands will be a good idea as opposed to using general services. I like the idea of segmenting the code out so that each command has a single responsibility, and that each command will be closed for modification so that the code won't easily get broken when adding new features. Plus, it's a new challenge!

My only concern about commands is server load. Does using the command bus dramatically decrease performance? If so, does the maintainability that it offers outweigh the performance losses?

**Edit**

I should have mentioned that the commands that I am worried about causing too much server load are synchronous commands. For example, adding a product to cart. I would be doing some asynchronous commands as well, such as adding a customer to the mailing list, but that's less of a concern. I just don't want the app to become slow and unresponsive.

Answer (score 0):

You could (and should) use Command Bus to put some slow logic.

To make sure that it will use only necessary system resources, you should use Daemon Queue Workers.

Take a look at [Laravel Docs (Daemon Queue Worker)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/queues#daemon-queue-worker)

Using the Daemon mode, the framework will not be re-booted at every command. This will reduce a lot of overhead.

Answer (score 0):

The entire bootstrap is loaded for commands. There would be little or negligible differences between running script via a command vs the opposite.

From the way you are talking, it seems like the commands will run administrative tasks(crud). If so, you may be better off creating a separate laravel instance that is only responsible for these crud operations. This could be put onto a separate server eliminating the code execution overhead debt you would generate by executing on the same instance that your customers are browsing.